# How to load images and text from sqlite in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, custom-adapter

I am working on an android project where images are displayed in Gridview which are hardcoded

I want to load images from an external source instead , below is code for Adapter class fetching images from drawable resource.Also i need to show some text with each image  , I am new to android development so please suggest an approach for loading text and image dynamically in Gridview from sqlite database(for text) and external storage (for image)

```
    package com.android.tabapp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
          private Context mContext;

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
        R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
        R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
        R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
        R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
        R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
        R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
        R.drawable.pic_15
    };


    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
       mContext = c;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      return mThumbIds.length;
  }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
  }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
       imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
       imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
       return imageView;
   }
 }
```

`

Comment: What's the problem? Just save and load the drawables as Ints in an SQLite database. Any basic tutorial will show you how to do that.

Comment: Is it a good practice to load images into sqlite database as int ?

Comment: No, you save a reference to an image. In your case, that reference is a static final int from the R class which points to one of your Drawable resources. Just look at the type of your mTumbIds array.